# Passing self-filled data explicitly in POST request

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I want to test redirection of Update View.

Reading the documentations, and looking at source code, I find: 
Update View instances self.object before processing the request (which helps it to set form fields to current value)

Now this is behavior I wanted, but is giving me trouble during testing.

My Models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default="")
    # Other fields
```

views.py

```
class UpdateProject(LogInRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

    form_class = ProjectUpdateForm
    template_name = 'project/create.html'
```

And In Testing:
(I have created a project and set up most things in setUp)

```
def test_redirection(self):
        # After updating project, users should land on correct page.[View Project page].
        self.client.login(username=self.owner.email, password=self.password)
        response = self.client.post(self.url, follow=True) # This will give error, since it requires Title field
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('project:show',
                                                kwargs={'project_id': self.project.id}))
```

Now, I know I can pass title explicitly with data field, but if I were to change the fields later in model, this test would also fail, which it shouldn't [It's only purpose is to check for redirection, there are other tests which deal with form validation, etc]

So, my question is: Is there a way to simulate Post Request as done by Update View (i.e. pass data context by setting object context to pre-filled values and only over-ride changed values]

Comment: One way to do what I want:
get_response = self.client.get(self.url)
response = self.client.post(self.url, data=get_response.context['object'].__dict__, follow=True)

This populates data field to current object, which is actually what is being done behind the scenes

Answer (score 0):

The view presumably only redirects on success. If you don't pass enough information for the view to succeed, then it shouldn't redirect. So it sounds like you want something impossible — you're wanting to test what the code does in a situation other than the situation you are setting up.

The question I have is: what is the value of this test? Why not just put it at the end of the test that checks for success?

I understand that the normal testing mantra is that you have a test for one thing only, but I think it's just impractical for this kind of scenario, and the cost is fragile tests that hack around the internals of something.

The other approach is that you split you write your tests like this:

```
def _submit_good_form_data(self):
    response = self.client.post(self.url, follow=True, data={'title':'The title')

def test_form_success(self):
    response = self._submit_good_data()
    # asserts here 

def test_redirection(self):
    response = self._submit_good_data()
    # asserts here
```

This way you only have one place to update when the nature of your form changes.

However, I'd question whether this is really worth it, seeing you are adding significantly to the length of the test run, and it doesn't actually give you the test independence you are really after (an error in the view will cause both tests to fail).

Comment: I considered it, but I had my form_test and view_test in different classes. But this sounds promising.

Comment: If you want to test the form individually, you should be able to factor out a method/function that populates the data to be passed to the form. If it's a function then you can just use it from both places, or if it needs to be a method then put it in a mixin.

Answer (score 0):

One way to replicate behind-the-scenes machinery:

```
    get_response = self.client.get(self.url)
    response = self.client.post(self.url, data=get_response.context['object'].__dict__, follow=True)
    self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('project:show', kwargs={'project_id': self.project.id}))
```

Not very pretty, but is basically what goes behind the scenes.